# React - Access a variable declared in componentDidMount() method in render() method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, color-picker, typescript

I'm using a color picker library in a react project called pickr, here is the link to the documentation on github : https://github.com/Simonwep/pickr. I used the `componentDidMount()` method and I want to access to a variable declared in it in order to get the color selected grom the color picker and show it another place at the same page.

I created a card ( a component from material ui components ) and I set it's color like this :

```
<Card width="10" height="10" color={pickr.getSelectedColor()}></Card>
```

```
// Libraries :
import React, { Component,Fragment } from 'react';
import Pickr from '@simonwep/pickr'; // documentation about this library : https://github.com/Simonwep/pickr 
import '@simonwep/pickr/dist/themes/classic.min.css';

import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';

export default class ColorPicker extends Component { 
   componentDidMount(){
        const pickr = Pickr.create({
            el: '.color-picker',
            theme: 'classic',
            swatches: [
                'rgba(244, 67, 54, 1)',
                'rgba(233, 30, 99, 0.95)',
                'rgba(156, 39, 176, 0.9)',
                'rgba(103, 58, 183, 0.85)',
                'rgba(63, 81, 181, 0.8)',
                'rgba(33, 150, 243, 0.75)',
                'rgba(3, 169, 244, 0.7)',
                'rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.7)',
                'rgba(0, 150, 136, 0.75)',
                'rgba(76, 175, 80, 0.8)',
                'rgba(139, 195, 74, 0.85)',
                'rgba(205, 220, 57, 0.9)',
                'rgba(255, 235, 59, 0.95)',
                'rgba(255, 193, 7, 1)'
            ],

            components: {

                // Main components
                preview: true,
                opacity: true,
                hue: true,

                // Input / output Options
                interaction: {
                    hex: false,
                    rgba: false,
                    hsla: false,
                    hsva: true,
                    cmyk: false,
                    input: true,
                    clear: true,
                    save: true
                }
            }
        });

    }


    render(){

        return(

            <Fragment>
                <div  className="color-picker"></div>
                <Card width="10" height="10" color={pickr.getSelectedColor()}></Card>

            </Fragment>
        )
    } 
}
```

The error:

> Line 60:  'pickr' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: Just make `pickr` a member of your component class

Answer (score 1):

Put the `pickr` variable in the `state` of the component:

```
// Libraries :
import React, { Component,Fragment } from 'react';
import Pickr from '@simonwep/pickr'; // documentation about this library : https://github.com/Simonwep/pickr 
import '@simonwep/pickr/dist/themes/classic.min.css';

import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';

export default class ColorPicker extends Component { 
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
                pickr: null
        };
    }  

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ 
            pickr: Pickr.create({
                el: '.color-picker',
                theme: 'classic',
                swatches: [
                    'rgba(244, 67, 54, 1)',
                    'rgba(233, 30, 99, 0.95)',
                    'rgba(156, 39, 176, 0.9)',
                    'rgba(103, 58, 183, 0.85)',
                    'rgba(63, 81, 181, 0.8)',
                    'rgba(33, 150, 243, 0.75)',
                    'rgba(3, 169, 244, 0.7)',
                    'rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.7)',
                    'rgba(0, 150, 136, 0.75)',
                    'rgba(76, 175, 80, 0.8)',
                    'rgba(139, 195, 74, 0.85)',
                    'rgba(205, 220, 57, 0.9)',
                    'rgba(255, 235, 59, 0.95)',
                    'rgba(255, 193, 7, 1)'
                ],

                components: {
                    // Main components
                    preview: true,
                    opacity: true,
                    hue: true,
                    // Input / output Options
                    interaction: {
                        hex: false,
                        rgba: false,
                        hsla: false,
                        hsva: true,
                        cmyk: false,
                        input: true,
                        clear: true,
                        save: true
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <Fragment>
                <div  className="color-picker"></div>
                <Card width="10" height="10" color={this.state.pickr.getSelectedColor()}></Card>
            </Fragment>
        )
    } 
}
```

Comment: I got this error : Unable to get property 'getSelectedColor' of undefined or null reference

Comment: I don't know the library `Pickr`, but maybe you can try to use this code in `render()` method: `<Card width="10" height="10" color={this.state.pickr && this.state.pickr.getSelectedColor()}></Card>`

Answer (score 0):

You can declare it as a constant in the file. Its not good in terms of performance to put it in the state object. State Object should have only those variables which are dynamic.
Check this Code

```
  // Libraries :
import React, { Component,Fragment } from 'react';
import Pickr from '@simonwep/pickr'; // documentation about this library : https://github.com/Simonwep/pickr 
import '@simonwep/pickr/dist/themes/classic.min.css';

import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';

const pickr = Pickr.create({
        el: '.color-picker',
        theme: 'classic',
        swatches: [
            'rgba(244, 67, 54, 1)',
            'rgba(233, 30, 99, 0.95)',
            'rgba(156, 39, 176, 0.9)',
            'rgba(103, 58, 183, 0.85)',
            'rgba(63, 81, 181, 0.8)',
            'rgba(33, 150, 243, 0.75)',
            'rgba(3, 169, 244, 0.7)',
            'rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.7)',
            'rgba(0, 150, 136, 0.75)',
            'rgba(76, 175, 80, 0.8)',
            'rgba(139, 195, 74, 0.85)',
            'rgba(205, 220, 57, 0.9)',
            'rgba(255, 235, 59, 0.95)',
            'rgba(255, 193, 7, 1)'
        ],

        components: {

            // Main components
            preview: true,
            opacity: true,
            hue: true,

            // Input / output Options
            interaction: {
                hex: false,
                rgba: false,
                hsla: false,
                hsva: true,
                cmyk: false,
                input: true,
                clear: true,
                save: true
            }
        }
    });


export default class ColorPicker extends Component { 
   componentDidMount(){

   }


render(){

    return(

        <Fragment>
            <div  className="color-picker"></div>
            <Card width="10" height="10" color={pickr.getSelectedColor()}> . 
   </Card>

        </Fragment>
      )
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the scope where the variable is defined. Since it is defined inside the componentDidMount method, the variable no longer exists outside of it. For it to exists outside of componentDidMount, it either needs to be defined in an outer scope, or attached to a variable that is accessible in both componentDidMount and render. The former would mean to move the declaration outside of the class, into the top level of the file. The second option would mean to add it as a property of the class by attaching it to `this`, or adding it as React state with `setState`. Of the two last ones, the first would be preferred if the color picker won't change (which would mean the component would need to render again).

With `this`:

```
export default class ColorPicker extends Component {

   componentDidMount(){
      this.setState({pickr: Pickr.create(/*...*/)});
   }
   render() {
      return(
            <Fragment>
                <div  className="color-picker"></div>
                <Card width="10" height="10" color={pickr.getSelectedColor()}></Card>
            </Fragment>
        )
   }
}
```

With `setState`:

```
export default class ColorPicker extends Component {
   constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state.pickr = null;
   }
   componentDidMount(){
      this.setState = Pickr.create(/*...*/);
   }
   render() {
      return(
            <Fragment>
                <div  className="color-picker"></div>
                <Card width="10" height="10" color={pickr.getSelectedColor()}></Card>
            </Fragment>
        )
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also set it as object property

```
componenDidMount() {
this.picker = Pickr.create({
        el: '.color-picker',
        theme: 'classic',
        swatches: [
            'rgba(244, 67, 54, 1)',
            'rgba(233, 30, 99, 0.95)',
            'rgba(156, 39, 176, 0.9)',
            'rgba(103, 58, 183, 0.85)',
            'rgba(63, 81, 181, 0.8)',
            'rgba(33, 150, 243, 0.75)',
            'rgba(3, 169, 244, 0.7)',
            'rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.7)',
            'rgba(0, 150, 136, 0.75)',
            'rgba(76, 175, 80, 0.8)',
            'rgba(139, 195, 74, 0.85)',
            'rgba(205, 220, 57, 0.9)',
            'rgba(255, 235, 59, 0.95)',
            'rgba(255, 193, 7, 1)'
        ],

        components: {

            // Main components
            preview: true,
            opacity: true,
            hue: true,

            // Input / output Options
            interaction: {
                hex: false,
                rgba: false,
                hsla: false,
                hsva: true,
                cmyk: false,
                input: true,
                clear: true,
                save: true
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Options:
1. put the variable into state and access it via this.state.pickr
2. you can declare a variable inside of 
`render() { var pickr = ... return ( <div> ... </div>) }`

Comment: Probably worth noting that moving it into render may cause unnecessary amount of work since the variable will be redelcared on each render. Depending on what the color picker does, it might degrade performance.

Answer (score 0):

create color state and set color state in componentDidMount()...

```
   import React, { Component,Fragment } from 'react';
 import Pickr from '@simonwep/pickr'; // documentation about this library : 
 https://github.com/Simonwep/pickr  
 import '@simonwep/pickr/dist/themes/classic.min.css';

  import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';

  export default class ColorPicker extends Component { 
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
            color: '',  //or set any other default color
    };
  }  

 componentDidMount() {
   const pickr = Pickr.create({
        el: '.color-picker',
        theme: 'classic',
        swatches: [
            'rgba(244, 67, 54, 1)',
            'rgba(233, 30, 99, 0.95)',
            'rgba(156, 39, 176, 0.9)',
            'rgba(103, 58, 183, 0.85)',
            'rgba(63, 81, 181, 0.8)',
            'rgba(33, 150, 243, 0.75)',
            'rgba(3, 169, 244, 0.7)',
            'rgba(0, 188, 212, 0.7)',
            'rgba(0, 150, 136, 0.75)',
            'rgba(76, 175, 80, 0.8)',
            'rgba(139, 195, 74, 0.85)',
            'rgba(205, 220, 57, 0.9)',
            'rgba(255, 235, 59, 0.95)',
            'rgba(255, 193, 7, 1)'
        ],

        components: {

            // Main components
            preview: true,
            opacity: true,
            hue: true,

            // Input / output Options
            interaction: {
                hex: false,
                rgba: false,
                hsla: false,
                hsva: true,
                cmyk: false,
                input: true,
                clear: true,
                save: true
            }
        }
    });
     const color=pickr.getSelectedColor()
     this.setState({color})
   }

   render() {
       return(
        <Fragment>
            <div  className="color-picker"></div>
            <Card width="10" height="10" 
             color={this.state.color}></Card>
         </Fragment>
        )
      } 
    }
```